# Bounds of UIScreen aren't accurate in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where pipes move up and down and I need to know the height of the screen so I know when the pipe should change directions. Here is the starting position of the pipes:

```
topPipe.position.y = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height + topPipe.size.height/2
bottomPipe.position.y = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height - bottomPipe.size.height/2 - emptyGap
```

I know how to do all of this and the pipes successfully move up and down, it works great on my iPhone 7+.  However, when I run it on the iPhone 5 simulator, the pipes only go about half way up the screen before coming back down.  It seems like UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height isn't returning the actual height of the screen it is running on. So, my app isn't compatible with any iPhones besides the 7+ because I manually set the screen size in gameScene.sks to 1080 × 1920.  Is there any other way to find the actual height of the screen?

In case you want to see how I'm actually moving the pipes (the anchor point for the screen is at the bottom left corner so I can just add the screen height and know where the top of the screen is and it's nice knowing that 0 is the very left side of the screen because the pipes stay along the left side):

```
//moves pipes
if topPipe.position.y - topPipe.size.height/2 >= UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height - 1{

bottomPipe.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: bottomPipe.position.x, y: 0 - bottomPipe.size.height/2), duration: movementDuration))

topPipe.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: bottomPipe.position.x, y: 0 + topPipe.size.height/2 + emptyGap), duration: movementDuration))

    } else if bottomPipe.position.y <= 0 - bottomPipe.size.height/2 + 1{

bottomPipe.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: bottomPipe.position.x, y: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height - bottomPipe.size.height/2 - emptyGap), duration: movementDuration))

topPipe.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: bottomPipe.position.x, y: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height + topPipe.size.height/2), duration: movementDuration))

    }
```

Comment: scaleMode exists so that you do not have to worry about different screen heights

Answer (score 1):

Ask for `bounds` instead of `nativeBounds`. Think in points, not pixels.

Comment: I changed all of the 'nativeBounds' to 'bounds' now the pipes seem to just barely move up and down in [this](http://i.imgur.com/LctXdeR.png).  I'm not sure why changing to 'bounds' caused the pipes to no longer move up and down the height of the screen. I will look through my code to see if this error is being caused by something else.